# Glitches on every Linux distros i boot /:

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel, distributions

I'm not much fan of writing a preface, so I cut to the chase. Here's the problem, I've been installing several Linux distros (e.g. Ubuntu, Elementary OS etc.) on my PC but as soon as it starts up and the desktop is shown, some graphical glitches happen on every single one of the distros. Dunno why. Though I think it might be due to the old hardware of mine. You see, dual core could and 4gb RAM. But if you have any on what's going on with the system or thought you could help, I'd be glad to hear from you. BTW, I try to add a photo of it.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux. You're tagging the question with `nvidia`, and NVIDIA can be quirky. I assume the desktop's unusable, but can you maybe press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F3` to try to access tty3? Using `Ctrl` + `Alt` with `F1` - `F6` gives you access to a command line interface, which can be used to investigate logs etc. If your system is old and underpowered, you should try a lightweight distro such as Lubuntu - googling for `lightweight linux for old pc` gives you a wealth of distros, all easy on the resources, some specifically targeted for older hardware.

Comment: You're probably running `nouveau` instead of NVIDIA drivers. Please consult with your distro manual how to install proprietary NVIDIA drivers.